# increase non sequential ones by one in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of 1s and 0s. I would like to replace the 1s with its "spot" in the vector.

For example I would like to change

```
 x = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

to

```
1 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 0 4
```

The numbers of 1s and 0s in a row can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it...

```
x = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

x[x==1] <- cumsum(c(x[1], diff(x)) == 1)[x==1]

x
 [1] 1 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 0 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `rle`

```
x * with(rle(x), rep(cumsum(values), lengths))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 0 4
```

We create a run-length sequence of `x` and repeat `cumsum` of `values` `lengths` time and multiply it by `x` so that 0's remain as 0's and only 1's are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `rle` and `inverse.rle`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values[values==1] <- seq_along(values[values==1])))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 0 4
```

---

Or an option using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
x1 <- rleid(x)
x1[x!= 0] <- rleid(x1[x!=0])
x1 * x
#[1] 1 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 0 4
```